# TFS Release - deploy same artifact(s) to different clients on different schedule(s)

Tags: tfs

50+ clients use same software (WEB, SQL, REST servers). They are all isolated and use different schedules for deployments.
At the moment we use XAML build definition that prepares code and deploys it in one run. This takes a lot of resources to compile same source code 50+ times but it allows us to deploy code to specific client at any schedule that client (or us) pick.
I would like to change the approach to build deployment package(s) once and deploy it/them for each client at their schedule.
Is it possible to set up in TFS Release? Maybe 50+ releases to use same build definition?
Keep in mind that most clients will get new version every night (just at different time), some may be getting updated weekly, some may ask to stop deployments for a while and resume at their command. So "weekly client" will have to get 7 releases to get current. "Paused clients" will have  number of packages accumulated that will have to be applied to their servers when they resume updates.
All packages are incremental, and we can't just use latest release.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: What version of TFS? What do you mean by "TFS Release"? There are at least 3 or 4 different things that could mean off the top of my head. Please **precisely** describe your current environment.

Comment: We use TFS 2015 at the moment. Upgrading to TFS 2017 (we still using XAML builds in some areas). We have PROD branch that has code for production sites. Same code is deployed to everyone at different times or day. I need a way to produce one package and deploy it to different clients at different schedules (some schedules are not known ahead of time so all packages are incremental). When client is ready to receive latest version, we must deploy all outstanding packages to bring them up to latest code.. thanks.

Comment: After playing a little in TFS Build and Release I was able to do this. Created a build definition that creates artifacts. Created multiple release definitions that consume those artifacts. I set release to be created every time new version of artifact is created and set release deployment on schedule. Everything looked promising until I collected several releases and scheduled deployment. They were deployed out of order even when selected to deploy one at a time. Is this a bug in TFS 2017 or I'm missing something. It can't be by design, why would one deploy release 5 before release 1 or 2...?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I was able to create a pipeline that creates release every time new build/artifact is created. Inside, I created different environments that can be set to deploy on any schedule individually. Everything is working great with exception of deployment of multiple releases. If I have 10 releases created and waiting to be deployed to QA environment at 3 AM. The TFS Release deployed them all one by one (per settings), but it is deploying them in random order. So, in the morning you may end up with changes from Release 1 or 3 or 7 on QA environment.

Contacted Microsoft support about this and got "this is by design" response.

I don't know who is behind such design, to me, it is major problem for release management and deployments.

Apparently, Azure DevOps server can achieve correct order of deployments but only in YAML pipelines. Classic pipelines still have this issue.